# Qt Src\qtbase directory is absent

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I just installed qt in my Windows (C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0). But, the ....\5.10.0\Src\qtbase directory is not there (C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0***5.10.0\Src\qtbase***).

Anyone have any idea, what might went wrong?

Comment: Maybe you didn't check the `Sources` box in the installer?

Comment: Exactly, that was the case. Thank you.